# Manually trigger angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular

I am seeing that it is very straightforward to enable it is very straight forward to enable/disable in-memory-web-api according to your documentation. I have been playing with scenarios in which the tester can enable/disable certain mock services from a dropdown modal.

I have not been able to subscribe to the service from my component.

```
export class InMemPatientService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
     const patients = [
        {
            id: 1,
            patient: "Adewumi, Anice (56, F)",
            facility: "Brighton",
            datesValid: "07/07/17 - 07/07/18",
            typeD: "Tx Hemo (CHG)",
            order: "Frequency 3 times per week; Treatment Time 4 hours 10 minutes per week (250)"
        },
        {
            id:2,
            patient: "Bowman, Jackson (56, M)",
            facility: "Brighton",
            datesValid: "06/07/17 - 07/07/18",
            typeD: "Tx Hemo (CHG)",
            order: "Frequency 3 times per week; Treatment Time 4 hours 10 minutes per week (250)"
        }
     ];
     return {patients}; ***//also attempting return Observable.of({patients}) ******
  }

}
```

I was hoping the subscription would be as simple as injecting the service into the component and doing

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
          private memPatientService: InMemPatientService) {}

 runMockServiceCheck() {
     if (!this.mockServiceCheck) {
     console.log("false");
  } else {
    this.memPatientService
     .createDb()
       .subscribe(patients => {
        this.patients = patients;
      }, 
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

However, I receive an error

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{ patients: ({ id: number; patient: string; facility: string; datesValid: string; typeD: string; ...'.
```

I am not sure if I am trying to do something that the library isn't meant for or if I am missing something in my code to enable this functionality.

** I did also try **Observable.of({patients})** but am getting an error of any on

```
 this.patients
```

inside of **subscribe**

Comment: How could you subscribe to createDb? You can see it doesn't return an observable. The point of the in-memory API is that you *make HTTP calls to it*, to simulate a real API. I think returning the observable, even if you provided types to avoid the implicit any, would break the interface with the mechanism that calls it; it's not designed for you to call it directly yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe honestly that is what I was thinking and have seen in my current edits.